# How to disable cloud messaging in flutter app?

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I am making an app with push notifications. These are already implemented with FirebaseMessaging.
This is the code for it:

```
_firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print("Message: " + message.toString());
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print("Message: " + message.toString());
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print("Message: " + message.toString());
    },
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
    print(token);
  });
```

I also have a settings page in the app. There it is possible for the user to uncheck the property for receiving notifications. Under the hood, it's just a variable that is set to false at the moment.
My question is: How is it possible to disable the push notifications for those users?

Comment: How are you sending the push messages? Are you sending them from a web server, with device tokens? or from the web console?

Comment: I am sending them from the web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Firebase topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) to only send notifications to devices which subscribed to a topic.

The firebase_messaging [also supports topics.](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/lib/firebase_messaging.dart#L92-L99)